# Rust repeat immutable variable

Tags: rust

I am new in Rust but I know a little bit a Python, and I have questions.

Why does the code below work without any exceptions:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello");
    let repeated_str = s1.repeat(4);
    println!("{}",repeated_str);
}
```

`s1` variable is not mutable. But we mutate `s1` using the `repeat()` method right? So why we can create a new variable using `s1`?

Maybe I didn't understand something when I read about ownership and reference.

Comment: You can't modify `s1` but the repeat method creates a copy. Thus, there are no errors.

Comment: so we use s1 copy in repead method ?

Comment: No, repeat creates a copy

Comment: This is exactly the way it works in Python too (all "mutating" `str` methods return a new modified `str`, leaving the original `str` unchanged), so this shouldn't be unfamiliar.

Comment: You get an entirely new `String` by calling [`str::repeat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.repeat). In this case, the docs also mention: "Creates a **new String** by repeating a string _n_ times."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `str::repeat` function does not actually mutate the given value, it only copies it. Hence, you are able to call the function without `s1` having the `mut` modifier.

This is explained in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.repeat) for repeat with the following line:

> Creates a new String by repeating a string n times.